# In Twitter Bootstrap, how would I stop all the accordions from momentarily unfolding on page load?

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

With reference to the following page:

http://www.myorange.ca/theme/jarvisadmin/

Upon page loading, all of the accordions on the left momentarily unfold and then hide again.  How can I stop this momentary unfolding as the page is loading?

Comment: Are you giving all of the non current LI's class of `closed`?

Comment: If what @DavidNguyen suggests is not the problem, then it might be that the accordion js hits too late.

Comment: That accordion isn't a bootstrap accordion. The title is a little misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Give all of the non open LI's that are suppose to be closed a class of `closed`

Answer (score 0):

change your navigation html
add class="closed" in main li on which menu open

like

```
<ul class="menu" id="accordion-menu-js">
    <li class="closed"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="icon-off"></i>Dashboard <span
        class="badge">2</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Dashboard</a> </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="logout-js" data-rel="login.html">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="closed"><a href="inbox.html" class="expanded"><i class="icon-envelope"></i>
        Inbox</a> </li>
    <li class=""><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="icon-check"></i>Forms<span class="badge">3</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="forms.html">Form Elements</a> </li>
            <li><a href="validation.html">Validation</a> </li>
            <li><a href="wizard.html">Wizards</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="closed"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="icon-user"></i>Interface<span
        class="badge">3</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="interface.html">Interface Elements</a> </li>
            <li><a href="buttons.html">Buttons &amp; Icons</a> </li>
            <li><a href="tables.html">Tables</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="closed"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="icon-signal"></i>Charts &amp;
        Graphs<span class="badge">3</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="basic_charts.html">Basic Charts</a> </li>
            <li><a href="adv_charts.html">Advanced Charts</a> </li>
            <li><a href="raphael.html">Raphael Engine</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="closed"><a href="widgets.html"><i class="icon-refresh"></i>Smart Widgets</a>
    </li>
    <li class="closed"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="icon-plus"></i>Bonus<span
        class="badge">4</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="invoice.html">Invoice</a> </li>
            <li><a href="typography.html">Typography</a> </li>
            <li><a href="chat.html">Chat</a> </li>
            <li><a href="error-page.html">Error Page</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```